# No Error shows but One line of pixels is wrong when export image in GEE

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT18U.png)

I am new here and I have a question about GEE. When add the image layer,I found there is one line of pixels is wrong as I showed in the picture. Number1 and 2 should be in the same value and color, but they just in the same value while the color is different; in addtion ,when export this image with .tif,and read it in ArcGIS ,the wrong pixels were still there but not in the same line, and they have different values where they should have the same value. so what's the problem? Does anyone know why? please contact me .Thanks very much.

Comment: it's done, just set the scale is ok.